# Sitecore SXA Multisite Robots.txt is returning 404 on one of CD servers

Tags: sxa, multisite

I have an issue on production environment that robots.txt is returning 404 on one CD server while it is working on the other.

Any suggestion if there is any missing configuration?

Comment: Are there any errors in the log files for the server its returning a 404 on? Anything else you can add for detail on the question? Right now, its really a shot in the dark as to what the problem might be.

Comment: Is something possibly cached on that CD server? If you have any logs, that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: There was no error logged from sitecore that expalin what is happening but the issue is fixed after recycling the app pool

Comment: Consider providing as answer to other people with this issue can resolve it quickly. Happy it was resolved for you.